# Conversion from PDF to TIFF file using XSLT

Tags: pdf, xslt, xslt-1.0, image-conversion, ibm-datapower

Is it possible to convert PDF to TIFF file using XSLT? Can someone point out some artcile or code i can refer regarding the image conversion using xslt.

THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible using **just** XSLT.  XSLT is for transforming XML to other textual structures (usually XML, HTML, or plain text).  Using XSL-FO, you can output a PDF from XML data - but that is a one way process as far as XSL-FO is concerned.  Apache FOP does support outputting to TIFF instead of PDF, but again this is a one way process.

Assuming you could get a PDF -> XML conversion working (a quick google suggests such libraries exist, but it's unclear what they'd actually provide), it would be possible to use XSLT to transform that XML into something Apache FOP could render into a TIFF file, but at that point you'd really be better off investigating a direct PDF to TIFF conversion library (perhaps with an OCR library).

Answer (score 0):

Possible? Maybe (but likely not). The real question is why do you even want to try to create a TIFF file from a PDF file using XSLT?

You do not need XSLT.

You want a raster image processor like Ghostscript (or many others). It can convert PDF (and Postscript) to other image formats like TIFF.

http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Devices.htm

Comment: I guess the "ibm-datapower" tag contradicts "You don not need XSLT" as that box has nothing but XSLT available (WTX set aside). At least for older versions. That said, I agree with your conclusion - do such things elsewhere, where there are appropriate tools available for the job.

Comment: I asked specifically for XSLT as I was told by someone that we can perform this conversion operation with it. It seems like we cannot.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is to call a conversion service, e.g. aspose.com or to create another service externally to the DataPower box.
There might be some Node.js modules that could do it running in GatewayScript (GWS) (if you are on firmware 7+) but I believe they are all dependent on external binaries to function and that won't work in GWS.